# Starting a SpringBoot app. in the 80 port

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to know if it is possible to start a SpringBoot app. in the 80 port,

I have set the port to 80, `server.port=0080`
but I am getting errors when init the app.

```
2019-03-31 12:52  [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol.log(173) - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
2019-03-31 12:52  [restartedMain] ERROR o.a.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.log(175) - Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1008)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:226)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:259)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at io.icrypts.ICryptsApplication.main(ICryptsApplication.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Comment: Just read the erorr message: Address already in use. You already have another server running in port 80.

Comment: Yes it's possible, but discouraged. You should use a server like nginx or apache that forwards the requests to your app instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ports with numbers 0–1023 are called system or well-known ports.

These are reserved ports and you should not run your applications in that port range.

In your exception you can read:

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

It means there's a service already using port 80. You can't bind your application on that port unless you find which service is already bound and kill it.

Again, it's discouraged to use ports 0–1023 for custom apps.

As already suggested, it's better to have an apache or nginx setup on port 80 that forwards the requests to your app (which should run on ports in the range 1024–49151). Example of how to setup reverse-proxy that forwards 80 to 8080 can be found [here](https://www.mkyong.com/nginx/nginx-apache-tomcat-configuration-example/).